# Consume a RESTful WS using Spring MVC and Jackson

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

I would like to consume a RESTful WS using Spring and Jackson.
I'm considering a JSON stream fetched by using Facebook Graph ([FC Juventus's JSON data-stream](http://graph.facebook.com/juventus))

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
public class ConsumeWSController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/consumews", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Consume a RESTful webservice.", locale);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Page page = restTemplate.getForObject("http://graph.facebook.com/juventus", Page.class);

        model.addAttribute("pageAbout", page.getAbout());
        model.addAttribute("pageAwards", page.getAwards());

        return "consumews";
    }

}
```

And the Page class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Page {

    private String about;
    private String awards;

    public String getAbout() {
        return about;
    }

    public void setAbout(String about) {
        this.about = about;
    }

    public String getAwards() {
        return awards;
    }

    public void setAwards(String awards) {
        this.awards = awards;
    }

 }
```

But the console returns this error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [my.proj.Page] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added the correct Jackson package to your classpath. For `Jackson 2`  and you use Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Or if you use the old `Jackson` add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm using com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind 2.3.0. Adding jackson-jaxrs-json-provider, eclipse returns a Maven error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define Jackson as your default message converter for `JSON` content. This is what I do (I use GSON so this might not be the exact syntax for the Jackson message converter):

```
 <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

But since you're not defining your `RestTemplate` as a Spring-managed bean, you need to do it manually:

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
```

PS. I see you're using the newer Jackson dependency so the proper mapper might be different in that case.